# linux 4.14 switch boot parition

Tags: boot

It's been two years since I modified my raspberry pi 3(model B).

In linux 4.1 I usually change the value of **/sys/module/bcm2709/parameters/reboot_part** to switch OS I want. But now I can't find it on linux 4.14.

Guys on IRC tell me it's no longer exist：

> [17:24]  Guest21160: it no longer exists. You can run 'reboot $part_no' instead

After command "reboot -f 5", it still boot from partition 1.

I think reboot command may need re-built, but does anyone know where I can get the source?

Comment: what bootloader do you use?

Comment: Now I use raspberry Pi 3 Model B+

Comment: I got an answer - some one had the same issue : https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2095

guys on IRC tell me that busybox's reboot implementation is unlikely to do it.

So I use the sample code above the link and solve this.

Answer (score 2):

OK, First thing is the **reboot_part** is no longer exist since RPI linux branch 4.8.y.

All the posts are outdated if they told you to change this attributes:

[Rebooting into a new OS](https://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=108071)

[Enlaces entre varios sistemas operativos](https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=150642#p1263773)

The answer for current RPI linux is simply use system call function below:

```
syscall(SYS_reboot, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2, reboot_part);
```

Most modern linux init system (upstart, systemd)  will implement their **reboot** command included the **SYS_reboot** system call.

So you simply can use command **"reboot 5"** to reboot from partition 5.

If you use busybox or something else that might not include this system call, you can just write your own, or just get a sample code from someone's post:

[how to reboot into partition with new firmware but no systemd?](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2095)

Here is the sample code I copied from the post above, thanks to **matthuisman**:

```
#include <linux/reboot.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    char *param = NULL;
    int cmd;

    if(argc == 2) {
        param = argv[1];
        cmd = LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2;
    }
    else {
        cmd = LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART;
    }

    sync();
    system("/etc/init.d/rcK || /etc/init.d/rc 0");

    sync();
    syscall(SYS_reboot, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, cmd, param);

    return 0;
}
```